# Change the text when you resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to know if it is possible to have a different text according to the device.

For example in 780px my `<p>` will show "hello world" and in 320 only "hello".

Thank you.
regards,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Go google `media queries`. Or click here, since you don't seem to possess that power: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You could wrap the text you don't want to see in a `<span>` for example, and they hide them based on the viewport width.

```
<p>Hello <span class="hide">world!</span></p>

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  p span.hide{
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 321px) {
  p span.hide{
    display: inline;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible. A simple way to do this would be:

```
var width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;

if(width > 1028){
  //display some text
} else if(width > 780) {
  //display other text
}
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate two texts on different divs.

Next with `css @media display` or not display this div's according to device.